# Can we confgure filters only for a subset of servlets

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have various different categories of servlets. Can I configure the filters in my web.xml such that each filter only applies for one of the categories of servlet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map them on `<servlet-name>` instead of `<url-pattern>`.

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilterName</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet1Name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet2Name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet3Name</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

The `<servlet-name>` must exactly match the same value as in `<servlet>` definition. This way the filter will be invoked whenever either of those servlets are to be invoked.